# @font-face works for one font, not the other

Tags: css, font-face

@font-face is driving me bonkers! What else is new?

I have this code in my stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: BebasNeue;
    src: url('/style/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular') format('svg'),
         url('/style/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/style/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.ttf') format ('truetype'),
         url('/style/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Quicksand;
    src: url('/style/fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.svg#Quicksand') format('svg'),
         url('/style/fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/style/fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/style/fonts/quicksand-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Quicksand loads, Bebas does not. I have re-downloaded the font (from Font Squirrel), reconverted it, pulled my hair out, prayed to Odin...

In Chrome's inspector I get an "Invalid CSS property value on the SVG line of the Bebas stylesheet, but I can't see any difference between that and the same line under Quicksand. In both Chrome and FF, quicksand-regular-webfont.woff shows up under resources, but -surprise!- not bebasneue-webfont.woff.

Comment: Can you link to a live example?

Comment: I believe you can omit the `format(XXX)`, anyway, you have a whitespace in the first .ttf between `format` and `(`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the mistake is here:

`src: url('/style/fonts/bebasneue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular') format('svg')`

and you have to write **...#bebasneue_regular** instead?